# Excel Macro to Loop through rows and display if it finds a certain value then continue when button is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to display certain values of a row in a userform if it matches a cell value from a different sheet. I need to be able to continue the search once i click a button and display the next matching record. here is the code i have so far

```
Private Sub NextRecord_Click()

Dim wst1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRowE As Integer
Dim lastRowF As Integer
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowE = Sheets("Raw Data (USSD Dials)").Cells(Sheets("Raw Data (USSD Dials)").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowF = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To lastRowE
foundTrue = False
For j = 1 To lastRowF

If Sheets("Raw Data (USSD Dials)").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 8).Value Then
    foundTrue = True
    Exit For
End If


AgentInterface.CustNameTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 2).Value & " " & Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 3)
AgentInterface.AccNoTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 7).Value
AgentInterface.CustNumTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 1).Value
AgentInterface.DueDateTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 4).Value
AgentInterface.MSISDNTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 8).Value
AgentInterface.ServiceNameTextBox = Sheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)").Cells(j, 5).Value


Next j


Next i

' stop screen from updating to speed things up`enter code here`
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is wrong with *the code you have so far*?

Comment: it is looping for a very long time and doesn't seem to match anything. Just ends up giving me details for the last row on the second worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to keep track of the last found rows between executions of the Sub

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub NextRecord_Click()
    Dim wsDials As Worksheet, lrDials As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsBills As Worksheet, lrBills As Long, agent As Object
    Static lastDials As Long, lastBills As Long

    Set wsDials = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data (USSD Dials)")
    Set wsBills = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data (Merchant Bills)")
    lrDials = wsDials.Cells(wsDials.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    lrBills = wsBills.Cells(wsBills.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Set agent = AgentInterface

    If lastDials = 0 Then lastDials = 1         'first run only (lastDials is static)
    If lastBills = 0 Then lastBills = 1
    If lastDials > lrDials Then lastDials = 1   'last run only (beyond UsedRange)
    If lastBills > lrBills Then lastBills = 1
    For i = lastDials To lrDials
        For j = lastBills To lrBills
            If wsDials.Cells(i, "C").Value = wsBills.Cells(j, "H").Value Then
                lastDials = i + 1
                lastBills = j + 1
                With wsBills
                    agent.CustNameTextBox = .Cells(j, "B").Value & " " & .Cells(j, "C").Value
                    agent.AccNoTextBox = .Cells(j, "G").Value
                    agent.CustNumTextBox = .Cells(j, "A").Value
                    agent.DueDateTextBox = .Cells(j, "D").Value
                    agent.MSISDNTextBox = .Cells(j, "H").Value
                    agent.ServiceNameTextBox = .Cells(j, "E").Value
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

The Sub "remembers" the last found rows between multiple runs by using 2 **static** variables

- They are initialized only when their value is 0 (first execution)
- And are re-initialized when their value is greater than their respective last row
- If a match is found it remembers both rows, and **exits both loops** (thus the sub)
- There is no perceived performance gained by turning off `ScreenUpdating`. In fact, for such a fast operation it might actually cause some flicker when you click the button, so I removed it

I'm not sure what `AgentInterface` is, but if it's a UserForm you should declare it as such

- `Dim agent As UserForm` (or whatever object type it is) to benefit from early binding it

Comment: Thanks, This really helped. i still have a challenge loading the next record. it takes a like 15-20 seconds to load. But i will try and crack that myself.

Comment: Hello i need a  few insights of how to save a value from another textbox to a cell on the row where we matched the value for the two cells

Comment: Is it related to this or can it be a new question? (others may respond faster)